# Making a page transition animation

Tags: animation, loading, transition

I recently noticed that some pages on the Internet (like Gizmodo and io9) have a page load animation. In the latter cases, the previous page is greyed out with a small loading "spinner" animation in the middle, and the second page comes in without a blank loading page in between, like most pages on the internet. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this works for you... the below solution worked for me although jQuery is needed:

First right after the body tag add this:

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Then add the style class for the div and image to your css:

```
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

And finally add this javascript to your page (preferably at the end of your page, before closing body tag of course):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
$(window).load(function() {
$('#loading').hide();   }); 
</script>
```

Then adjust the position of the loading image and the background color of the loading div via the style class.

This is it, works just fine. But of course you have to have an ajax-loader.gif somewhere.

Try [AJAXLoad](http://www.ajaxload.info/) They have some great animated GIF's there.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the referenced sites but it sounds like a jQuery candidate.

You use an ajax call to get the content of the page and then load it into the current DOM as a replacement for whatever is currently displayed.

The jQuery framework has animations as well as plugins to display the behavior you describe.  One I like is ColorBox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox).